# converting a 100V 900W AC electric kettle into 230V 1000W AC kettle

Tags: resistors

I bought this 100V 900W 50-60Hz AC kettle I really like in Japan, unaware that the power supply was different there than in my country (France, 230V 50Hz).

I tried it once with an adaptor on my european supply, and while it worked, I could smell that it overheated so I decided not to use it ever again if I don't find a fix for safety reasons.

I looked at the electronics of this kettle and it consists in a big resistor that is complety welded with the bottom of the kettle. Being like that, the only way I can increase the resistor is by adding one in parallel and welding it too to the bottom of the kettle.

If I am correct, I should be adding a resistor which value can be computed through:
$$
R_{new} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{(220V)^2}{1000W}-\frac{1}{R_{old}}}
$$

So I need to know what is R_old.
But here is where I am confused.

On the actual resistor, the number 2200 is written. I don't understand what it means, because if I use
$$
P = 900W = \dfrac {V^2} R = 10 000/R
$$
to infer the actual resistor R, I obtain R = 11.11 ohms

**Am I wrong with this inference? What could 2200 means?**

Comment: A physicist might not be able to tell the difference between a resistor and a heating element, but an electrical engineer knows the difference, and the electrical engineer might not expect markings on them to mean the same things.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks I didn't know. So what could it mean here? it is another unit?

Comment: This question had an edit that partially invalidated my answer so, I have rolled it back to how it was originally phrased.

Answer (score 4):

> t*he only way I can increase the resistor is by adding one in parallel
> and welding it too to the bottom of the kettle.*

**Absolutely not**. Putting resistors in parallel lowers the net resistance. You need to either (a) increase the resistance or (b) lower the supply voltage.

I'd favour lowering the supply voltage so, why not use a step-down transformer or a 1 kW switching converter. As a complete bodge, you could try using a triac circuit reduce the RMS voltage to a suitable level but, the kettle would still be potentially seeing peak voltages that might cause safety issues with the plastic insulation internally.

If you wanted to go down the route of adding a series resistor and welding it to the base of the kettle you will still have problems of insulation ratings in the cord and, the plug and, any internal wiring.

Comment: thanks for pointing my mistake out, I didn't check the validity of my calculation. I fixed it as I still can do it in series, so the question remains

Comment: I'm sorry @MiKiDe but once an answer has been posted you have to be extremely careful on how you make amendments to your question so, on this occasion I have rolled-back your question to how it stood originally. I will state that adding a resistor in series is probably invalidating the safety of it.

Comment: This is an engineering site so, safety has to be a big consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the kettle as you suggest is not a good plan. You won't get good thermal contact, the switch might not be rated for 240v, and it will leave you with an unsafe item.

Get a suitable transformer (a 230V-110V site transformer would be a good bet) and use that.